# The named parameter 'column' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name

Tags: flutter, dart

`The named parameter 'column' isn't defined.  Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'column'. Open documentation.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Device Details"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body : SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
            **Column**: <Widget>[
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  getImageWidget(),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      MaterialButton(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: Text(
                            "Camera",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            getImage(ImageSource.camera);
                          }),
```

If I replace column with "body" at  **column:SingleChildScrollView(**

then it is saying as The argument for the named parameter 'body' was already specified.

Please fix my issue by giving your valuable suggestions.

```
class _MyFormPageState extends State<MyFormPage> {

  File _selectedFile;
  bool _inProcess = false;

  Widget getImageWidget() {
    if (_selectedFile != null) {
      return Image.file(
        _selectedFile,
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    } else {
      return Image.asset(
        "assets/placeholder.jpg",
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    }
  }

  getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    this.setState((){
      _inProcess = true;
    });
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    if(image != null){
      File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
          sourcePath: image.path,
          aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(
              ratioX: 1, ratioY: 1),
          compressQuality: 100,
          maxWidth: 700,
          maxHeight: 700,
          compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
          androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            toolbarTitle: "RPS Cropper",
            statusBarColor: Colors.deepOrange.shade900,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          )
      );

      this.setState((){
        _selectedFile = cropped;
        _inProcess = false;
      });
    } else {
      this.setState((){
        _inProcess = false;
      });
    }
  }

  final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
  String companyname,modelname,series,mfgyear;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                getImageWidget(),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MaterialButton(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: Text(
                          "Camera",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          getImage(ImageSource.camera);
                        }),
                    MaterialButton(
                        color: Colors.deepOrange,
                        child: Text(
                          "Device",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          getImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                        })
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            (_inProcess)?Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.95,
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ):Center()
          ],
        ),

      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(" Details"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      
      **column** : SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          image: new DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.grey.withOpacity(.5),BlendMode.dstATop),
            image: new AssetImage(
              "asset/bg00.jpg"
            ),
          ),
        ),
        height: height,
        width: width,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Enter the Device Details",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),


              TextField(
                onChanged: (val){
                  companyname=val;
                },
                cursorColor: Colors.black,
                style: TextStyle(
                    height: 1
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey[500],
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.edit,color: Colors.blue[900],),
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color:Colors.black,
                  ),
                  hintText: "Enter the Company Name",
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the layout, so I can recommend feasible way to implement it.

Comment: ok  am sharing the screenshot now after editing my question. Please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the doc for [Scaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html). There is no properties named `column` indeed.

I think you have your SingleChildScrollView in the wrong place.

It should be un the body which contains a `Stack` with a `Column` at the moment. Not sure about what u want to achieve visually but yous might need to check in that direction. (Maybe putting the SingleChildScrollView at the end of said `Column`)

Comment: Please be little brief I did'nt get you  what If I have double "body" or double "colum"  i.e already defined. Please explain me two cases                                                                           1st Case at return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(    )     and                                                                                                 
   2nd Case at   appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(""),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),body: SingleChildScrollView   child: Container (  
    )

Comment: You can's have two `body` Inside `Scaffold`. But your `body` can have a widget that contains everything you need.

Comment: How to define   in such cases. These errors come frequently. Please suggwest me a permanent solution so as "How to define  anything any where?

Answer (score 0):

Check out if there is conflicting in the imported packages, this error has happened with me when I used "Variable" from moor.dart library. I resolved the error by converting the import statement to import 'moor.dart' as moor.

I know I'm too late, but for other people who gets crazy from this error.